# OpenCV4Android - findChessboardCorners doesn't find corners

Tags: android, opencv, camera-calibration

I want to find chessboard corners on an image using opencv functions. To do, I used below code. I have an android application. It gets frame and shows it. When user click on device screen, this code tries to find corners on selected frame.

My board has 6x5 squares.
Code :

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    if(!isClick) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    }
    else {

        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRgb, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
        findChessBoard();
        return mRgb;
    }
    return mRgba;
}

public void findChessBoard()
{
    int boardH = 5,
        boardW = 4;
    Size board_sz = new Size(boardW, boardH);
    MatOfPoint2f corners = new MatOfPoint2f();
    boolean found = Calib3d.findChessboardCorners(mRgb, board_sz, corners, Calib3d.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | Calib3d.CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

    if (found)
    {
        // Refines the corner locations
        Mat gray = new Mat(mRgb.size(), Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        Imgproc.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, new Size(11, 11), new Size(-1, -1),new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS, 0, 0.01));
                                                        //new TermCriteria(CV_T CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
        Calib3d.drawChessboardCorners(mRgb, board_sz, corners, found);
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Found " + corners.size() + " " + found);
}
```

Comment: From findChessboardCorners() documentation: `@param image Source chessboard view. It must be an 8-bit grayscale or color image.`